# How to force llvm cmake to use only given path to libs?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, llvm

I try to build llvm on a system where I have **no root access**. So, I've got some problems: I have been obliged to install `gcc`, `cmake` in my `$HOME` path because system's `gcc` and `cmake` are very old and I cannot update them with `sudo`.

I finely installed `gcc` and `cmake` and mentioned new paths to `PATH` env variable. I ran `cmake` for `llvm` with this:

```
cmake -S llvm -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=all -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;lld" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/my_user/local  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/home/my_user/local/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/my_user/local/lib ../llvm
```

It successfully generate make-file. When I run, it throws:

```
../../../../bin/clang-tblgen: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by ../../../../bin/clang-tblgen)
../../../../bin/clang-tblgen: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ../../../../bin/clang-tblgen)
...
```

but I've already got convenient  `libstdc++.so.6` in my `/home/my_user/local/lib64` and `/home/my_user/local/lib` when I installed new `gcc` but I don't understand how to force `cmake` or `make` to consider only these paths instead `/lib64`.
What an option should I pass to `cmake` or do I need to add some env variable to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked out for me.
Find out what a path contains needed libraries (in my case it is `/home/my_user/local/lib64` and then run
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/my_user/local/lib64 make`!